# Determine whether the set $\{x, x + y, xy : x, y\in \mathbb R\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine whether the set $\{(x, x + y, xy) : x, y\in \mathbb R\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

It does not need to be in proper proof form however I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How are you embedding the line in three-space? I am puzzled?

Comment: What precisely, in your usage, distinguishes a space from a set?  The set is clearly a sub*set* of R^3.  The only question therefore, is is it a space?  Well, what's your definition of space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $(1,2,1)$ is in the set.  Is $2(1,2,1)=(2,4,2)$ also in the set?